# Trigger email when task due date equals TODAY

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-email

I have a task list assigned to various users. I would like to trigger an automated email to the *Assigned To* user when the value of the *Start Date* column equals **Today**. What would be the best way to do this? I have been looking at workflows and [Power Automate](https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/), but it's quite intimidating to a new user.

[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? Have you build any workflow/power automate flow and it is causing issue or you are just trying to figure out which one to use?

Comment: check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/FLOW-TO-SEND-EMAIL-WHEN-DATE-APPROACHES/td-p/149139), [this](https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2018/03/using-flow-to-send-email-reminder-from-sharepoint-data/) and [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Email-Trigger-based-upon-column-date/m-p/129990). You will get some idea about it.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap those links were really helpful. Yes I am using SharePoint online. I nearly have a flow working but I can't seem to use a task list for the Get Items action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ganesh's link is helpful. Please have a check on them. I made a sample flow here which checks the start date column in my list everyday and send an email when it equals today. Follow the tutorial in second link provided by Ganesh and my example here is trying to make you to carry it out a bit more easily.

The Recurrence trigger makes sure the flow runs everyday, the get items action helps you to get all the items you need. Here is a bit tricky part about filling in the Filter Query if you have no idea how to do it. According to your goal, the query shall be like

> StartDate eq `'formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')'`

StartDate is your internal column name. For how to get the internal name, check this [blog](https://blogit.create.pt/fabiocarvalho/2017/05/26/sharepoint-online-internal-fields-names-how-to-use-spservices-to-get-them/). The internal name is not always same with the name you find in UI.

And you can see Red box where I insert an expression directly which is `formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')`. It gives you the date of today. Then use the `Apply to each` action in `Condition` which will do the same action for all the items you get from the `Get the items` action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful and taught me a lot. I created a sample list and the flow works perfectly. However, only lists show in the Get Items action and not task lists.Is it possible to do this with a task list?

Comment: @JohnGIS Have a try to use the custom value like this :https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/task-list/td-p/76538